# Shopify API - Get all products (60k products) Got Request Time Out or socket hang up

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, promise, shopify

I am trying to get all of products but I got Request timed out while trying to get 60k products for inventory management app.

I am using nodejs to loop into 200 pages, each page limit to 250 products. I limited 2 requests ever 10 seconds for my calls (5 seconds/1 request)

sometime I got these errors one some pages. Sometimes not

- read ECONNRESET
- Request timed out
- socket hang up

Could any one please tell me what is the problem? I would appreciate your help.

```js
for (var i = 1; i<= totalPage;i++)

{

  var promise = shopify.product.list({limit:limit,page:i,fields:fields})

  .then(products =>{

  // do some thing here when got products list
    // loop through each product then save to DB
    // ShopifyModel.updateOne(.....)

  }).catch(error=>{

  // some time it fired error here 

  })

}
```

I also tried to rewrite a function to get products of 1 page:

```js
const request = require('request-promise');

var getProductOnePage = function (Url_Page,headers,cb){
    request.get(productUrl, { headers: headers,gzip:true })
    .then((ListProducts) => {
        console.log(" Got products list of one page");
        cb(ListProducts);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        // Got All Error Here when try to put into for loop or map or forEach with promise.all
        console.log("Error Cant get product of 1 page: ",err.message);
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**
I found some problem similar to my case here:
https://github.com/request/request/issues/2047
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/312

Comment: did you test to get all of the data in one query instead off looping through pages?

Comment: Shopify only let you get 250 products each request. So I have to loop through 240 pages to get all 60k products.

Answer (score 1):

- `ECONNRESET` and `Request timed out` errors are there mostly due to network problem. Check if you have a stable internet connection.
- If you're using shopify api node package, then use autoLimit property. It will take care of rate limiting.

eg:

```
const shopify = new Shopify({
    shopName: shopName,
    apiKey: api_key,
    password: password,
    autoLimit : { calls: 2, interval: 1000, bucketSize: 30 }
});
```

**Edit**: Instead of writing then catch inside a for loop, use async await. Because weather you implement request and wait approach or not, for loop will send all requests. But if you use await, it will process one request at a time.

```
let getProducts = async () => {
    for (var i = 1; i<= totalPage;i++)
    {
        try {
            let products = await shopify.product.list({limit:limit,page:i,fields:fields});
            if(!products.length) {
                // all products have been fetched
                break;
            }
            // do you stuffs here
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I tried few ways to limit request. and I think it works for my code: `autoLimit : { calls: 2, interval: 10000, bucketSize: 30 }` and also `shopify.request = valvelet(shopify.request, 2, 10000)` 
I also tried to write my own request but got same problem.
tried to add gzip to my request, it seems I got less Error than before.

Comment: can you please check the updated answer and let me know if it worked ? and also can you find for which page are you getting the error ? And try to make that a request separately for that page ?

Comment: the error pages display randomly, sometime it is 140 sometime 104 or 100. It's OK if I try to request 1 page separately. but try to do inside loop got the errors.
it seems my code got some memory leak too. I will try your code and let you know the result. thanks

Comment: Got the error why tried your code: `let products = await shopifyAPI.product.list({limit:limit,page:i,fields:fields});
                               ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)`

Comment: I also update a function to get products of one page separately. sitll got same error at some page

Comment: Before createScript function add async keyword.
async createScript () {...}

Comment: It's like your car is out of gas, yet you keep checking if it is the air in the tires keeping you from driving. Learning how your tools actually work will go a long way to helping you out here. Willy nilly pasting other peoples' codes will never work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the concept of rate limiting. With any public API like Shopify, you can only make so many calls before they put you on hold. So when you get a response back from Shopify, you can check the header for how many requests you can make. If it is zero, you'll get back a 429 if you try a request.

So when you get a 0 for credits, or a 429 back, you can set yourself a little timeout and wait to make your next call.

If on the other hand, as you say, you are only doing 2 calls every 10 seconds (not at all clear from your code how you do that, and why??) and you're getting timeouts, then your Internet connection to Shopify is probably the problem.

Comment: I did something like this:` shopify.request = valvelet(shopify.request, 2, 10000)` and `autoLimit : { calls: 2, interval: 10000, bucketSize: 30 }`
and I don't think it's the internet connection from my end, because I have tested on multiple server, got the same problem.